# Remove the subdirectory where a WordPress is installed from the URL structure

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a Xenforo installed on root / and a WordPress installed in a subdirectory /wp/. Wordpress posts URLs have now this stracture site.com/wp/articles/some-post-title/ and I need an Nging rewrite to change them to site.com/articles/some-post-title/.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, there are alot of infos around about this exact topic, consider expanding your google-foo searches a bit and you should find what you are looking for. As far as a 'question'... my answer would still be 'yes, it is possible' - maybe refine your question in order to attract more interrest and have a better chance at relevant information. Oh, also... Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow, WordPress allows you to install it into a subdirectory, but have your website served from the website root.

Here's the article to help you set it up!
https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/

Comment: Hello Mohammed,

Instructions are for Apache htaccess. Any way to translate to Nginx rewrite?

Comment: this is your solution: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/
This will help you map directories to urls